# Why stripped_string output is not separated by comma?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, lxml

I wanted to extract a specific br tag(the last br tags in each li like (text4,text7,text11) in li tags :

```
<li class="odd"> text1 <br>   text2 <br>   text3 <br>    text4</li>
<li class="odd"> text5  <br>   text6  <br> text7 </li>
...
<li class="odd"> text8 <br>   text9  <br>  text10  <br>   text11</li>
```

and this the code I used:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
URL = '...'
content = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'lxml')
contentTable  = soup.find_all("li", {"class": "odd"})
for li in contentTable:
    li_contents = list(li.stripped_strings)
    print(li_contents)
```

and the output is like this:

```
[text1 text2 text3 text4 ]
[text5 text6 text 7]
[text8 text9 text10 text11]
...
```

the problem is that the texts are not separated by commas, and I want the last text of every list, how can I solve this problem?
the output I want:

```
[text4]
[text7]
[text11]
...
```

Comment: ``print(li_contents.split()[-1])`` ?

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' objet has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.contents` with `[-1]` to access the last element.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<li class="odd"> text1 <br>   text2 <br>   text3 <br>    text4</li>
<li class="odd"> text5  <br>   text6  <br> text7 </li>
<li class="odd"> text8 <br>   text9  <br>  text10  <br>   text11</li>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for li in soup.select('li.odd'):
    print(li.contents[-1].strip())
```

Prints:

```
text4
text7
text11
```

Comment: doesn't work!output is not even a list text1 :text2 text3 text4 
text5 text6 text 7
text8 text9 text10 text11
...

Comment: @KeyvanDarnell I don't understand. What output do you want then?